# How to initialize variables defined in tensorflow function?

Tags: python, tensorflow

In TensorFlow, I want to define a variable inside a function, do some processing and return a value based on some calculations. However, I cannot initialize the variable inside the function. Here is a minimal example of the code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def foo():
    x = tf.Variable(tf.ones([1]))
    y = tf.ones([1])
    return x+y

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
        sess.run(init)
        print(sess.run(foo()))
```

Running the code yields the following error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value Variable
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Before you initialize all variables, the function foo() has not been called at all. So it fails to initialize the variables in foo(). We need to call the function before we run the session.

```
import tensorflow as tf

def foo():
    x=tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))
    y=tf.ones([1])
    return x+y

with tf.Session() as sess:
    result=foo()
    init=tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init)
    print(sess.run(result))
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not defining those variables into default `tf.Graph` before initializing them.

```
import tensorflow as tf


def foo():
    x = tf.Variable(tf.ones([1]))
    y = tf.ones([1])
    return x + y


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with tf.Graph().as_default():
        result = foo()
        with tf.Session() as sess:
            init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
            sess.run(init)
            print(sess.run(result))
```

This code defines the variables into the `tf.Graph` before intializing them as requested, so you can execute them at your `tf.Session` through `sess.run()`.

Output:

> [2.]

Comment: Based on lishu's suggestion, the problem was with calling the foo function not the graph.

Comment: Hi again @mhrtsh! Seems that you can add some variables to the `tf.Graph` after starting `tf.Session`, my bad. Anyway, the problem was trying to initialize through `sess.run()` some variables not previously defined into the `tf.Graph`. Typical approach in Tensorflow is to first define the `tf.Graph` and then start a `tf.Session`.

Comment: I have edited my answer clarifying that problem was in not defining those variables into the `tf.Graph` before initializing them.

Answer (score 0):

You should use,

`tf.global_variables_initializer()`

after starting your `Session` to initialize variables.

[Tensorflow Variable](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable)